# How could I apply the return value of a method as a parameter for another method?

Tags: java

I've been working on this for awhile, but I can't seem to find the solution to this problem. Here is some pseduocode to clarify my problem:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Enter your character: ");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String inEntry = in.next();
    entryBuilder(inEntry); //this is where entrybuilder takes in an input
public static void findWord(){
     if (validWord(INSERT RETURN FROM METHOD ENTRYBUILDER HERE)){
          //some code
public static String entryBuilder(String input){
    String a = input;
    String prefix = "";
    prefix += a;
    return prefix;
}
```

I can't seem to understand how to piece this together. Any help is appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: `public static void findWord(){` needs to take a parameter `public static void findWord(String word`){`, then you can just feed in what ever value you need

Comment: you can do this: `public static void findWord(String word){ if(validWord(word)){ //some code` and use this `String word = entryBuilder(inEntry);`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Enter your character: ");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String inEntry = in.next();
    entryBuilder(inEntry); //this is where entrybuilder takes in an input
       findWord("you word") //  or findWord(methodThatReturnsString());
    }

public static void findWord(String word){
     if (validWord(INSERT RETURN FROM METHOD ENTRYBUILDER HERE)){
          //some code
}
public static String entryBuilder(String input){
    String a = input;
    String prefix = "";
    prefix += a;
    return prefix;
}
public String methodThatReturnsString(){
      return "some strings";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the String value inside findWord somehow, so:

```
public static void findWord(){

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String inEntry = in.next();

     if (validWord(entryBuilder(inEntry))){
          //some code
}
```

Though it would probably be better to define the Scanner outside this method, then pass the Scanner as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do ?

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String inEntry = "A test string";
        String entry = entryBuilder(inEntry);
        findWord(entry);
    }

    private static void findWord(String s){
        if (validWord(s)) {
            System.out.println(s + "is valid");
        }
    }

    private static String entryBuilder(String input){       
        String prefix = "";
        prefix += input;
        return prefix;
    }

    private static boolean validWord(String s) {
        return ! s.trim().isEmpty();
    }
```

(posting [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is a good practice)

Comment: Yes, this would be how you would solve this question. I figured it out this morning. Thanks for the help!